# Add UITapGestureRecognizer to dynamically added views

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Im having some issues with adding tapRecognizers to my views.
Im adding an unknown number of events, news and coupons to my UIScrollView where on click i want to open an detail view. However on click the app crashes with following error

```
Almhults_appen.MainActivity redirectFromHomeScreen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f93c2d4df20

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Almhults_appen.MainActivity redirectFromHomeScreen:]:
```

As I see it I could make use of an UITableView and add all views to it. However if possible I would personally like to avoid it but since I'm new to Swift I don't trust my judgement here.

```
if (!event_ar.isEmpty) {
    for event: Event in event_ar {

        ... Init EventView and add to UIScrollView

        // Add tapGesture
        let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: "redirectFromHomeScreen:"
        )
        eventView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}
if (!news_ar.isEmpty) {
    ... Add news identically to events
}
if (!coupon_ar.isEmpty) {
    ... Add coupons identically to events
}
```

Edit added action function

```
private func redirectFromHomeScreen(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void{
    ... Do stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your crash report .. first you need to declare funtion

```
func redirectFromHomeScreen (sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){

}
```

Declare this and try again

Comment: Added redirectFromHomeScreen() to question.

As of now it is declared as private is that something that may cause trouble

Comment: Silly me the problem I had occurred due to redirectFromHomeScreen() being declared as private.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your gesture to the view you will tap on. And the best moment to add it is within that view's viewDidLoad method. With Objective-C I do that and it works well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer  *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(PanToFlipPage:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

}

Comment: As of now I'm adding views and and tapGestures inside a separate function called from viewDidLoad. As i can see moving the populate of scrollview to viewDidLoad would not impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these lines after you have created all of your subviews and buttons.

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```